# Is this a real warning or an over-sensitive lint?

Tags: java, findbugs

I have this method:

```
private Boolean compare(String property, String relationOperator,
        String operand) {
    Integer propertyValue = NumberUtils.toInt(property);
    Integer operandValue = NumberUtils.toInt(operand);

    switch (relationOperator)
    {
        case "<":  return propertyValue.compareTo(operandValue) < 0;
        case "<=": return propertyValue.compareTo(operandValue) <= 0;
/*WARN*/case "=":  return propertyValue.compareTo(operandValue) == 0;
        case ">=": return propertyValue.compareTo(operandValue) >= 0;
        case ">":  return propertyValue.compareTo(operandValue) > 0;
        case "!=": return propertyValue.compareTo(operandValue) != 0;
    }
    return Boolean.FALSE;
}
```

For the line marked `/*WARN*/`, FindBugs 3.0.0 tells me:

> Suspicious comparison of Integer references in 
>    com.foo.MyClass.compare(String, String, String) [Scariest(1), High 
>    confidence]

I think the code is OK as I am comparing `int`s not `Integer`s, so can I safely `@SuppressWarnings` on this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is scary because it uses wrapper classes and comparable when it could use primitives. Also, your code is overly clever. You should try to [**write dumb code**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/devinsight-1-139780.html). Something like,

```
private boolean compare(String property, String operator, String operand) {
    int pv = Integer.parseInt(property);
    int ov = Integer.parseInt(operand);
    if (operator.equals("<")) {
        return pv < ov;
    } else if (operator.equals("<=")) {
        return pv <= ov;
    } else if (operator.equals(">")) {
        return pv > ov;
    } else if (operator.equals(">=")) {
        return pv >= ov;
    } else if (operator.equals("!=")) {
        return pv != ov;
    } else if (operator.equals("=") || operator.equals("==")) {
        return pv == ov;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes the warning go away. I initially chose `Integer` to match existing code that used `String.compareTo()`.

Comment: There's no advantage to a bunch of `if..else` chains over `switch` here, since Java now supports switching on `String`. If refactoring is called for, it would be to pull the comparison out into an enum.

Answer (score 5):

Since `compareTo` returns a primitive `int`, you're correct, and this code is fine. I recommend submitting this as a bug against FindBugs.

As a note, you're also causing unnecessary autoboxing for your variables. You can just store them in `int`s and use `Integer.compare(propertyValue, operandValue)`.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the code is OK as I am comparing ints not Integers, so can I safely @SuppressWarnings on this line?

I supposed you could.  (I don't see anything intrinsicly unsafe in what you are doing.)

However, you are incorrect in your belief that you are comparing `int`s.

You have declared `propertyValue` and `operandValue` as `Integer`, and therefore the `compareTo` call is comparing `Integer` objects.  (Albeit in a way that is safe ...)  I'm pretty sure that *that* is what FindBugs is complaining about.

See Elliot Frisch's Answer for a better way to write the code ... that is most likely faster, and that won't irritate FindBugs.